# How do I include a "cell value" in a textbox together with texts

Tags: excel, textbox

Thanks for reading in advance.

I have been doing financial reporting for just a few months and find that it is a pretty routine commentary hence I wish to automate this process.

I have a textbox in Excel which says "This month income is **$500**, and it is **$50** below budget".

The thing is , the values change every month hence instead of keying in the values, I wish for them to refer to a specific cell say range("A1").Value; How do I go about including those strings and the values I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to do this in 2 steps.

1. Use a cell with a formula that combines the different parts of the text you need;
2. Make the textbox refer to that cell.

For example, this would look like this:
[image]

And the formula in D1 would be

```
="This month income is $" & B1 & ", and it is $" & B2 &" below budget"
```

Then, to make the texbox take the value you want, you would have to click inside and write in the formula bar: `=$D$1`

Note that textboxes formulas can only contain direct references to a cell, so more complex formulas are not allowed. That's why we need the cell D1 as an intermediate step.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That clarifies and hope you have a good TGIF !

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Excel CONCATENATE function.

For example:

```
=CONCATENATE("This month income is $", A1, "and it is", A2, "below budget")
```